# BeautifulSoup not getting all HTML elements anymore while it did yesterday and no code was changed

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

The source variable is not getting all the HTMl elements but it was before. Nothing was changed and I don't know what to do. I'm very new to coding. I'm trying to extract a list of songs and artists off my apple music playlist and before this worked fine but now the HTML is not appearing as it does on inspect element on the website.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://music.apple.com/us/playlist/vibe-check-1/pl.u-JPAZE8Gul2rRBZ0').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

print(soup.prettify()) 

links = soup.find('div', {"class":"songs-list typography-caption"})


song_names = links.find_all('div', {"class": "song-name typography-label"})
artist_name = links.find_all('div', {"class":"by-line typography-caption"})
```

Comment: Does that website use javascript to dynamically add/alter the page content?  `requests` can't do javascript.

Comment: I'm not sure if it uses javascript or not but it was working as I intended yesterday and suddenly stopped without changing any code, so I didn't think that was the problem. But if it is, what can I use to extract javascript and do you have any idea why it just suddenly stopped ?

Comment: Actually that would exactly explain the problem, if that site wasn't using javascript yesterday but the site owners changed it today to use javascript.

Comment: The website is from Apple Music and it looks exactly the same and I'm still able to see all the same classes that I reference in my code when I inspect element, but when I view page source I don't see any of the classes and that's why `soup.find` returns none. So do you think its likely that's what happened still?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is loaded dynamically, therefore `requests` doesn't support it. However, it's possible to scrape the data by sending a `GET` request to their API with adding the correct authorization.

There's also no need for `BeautifulSoup`, this can be done with just the `requests` module.

```
import requests


URL = "https://amp-api.music.apple.com/v1/catalog/us/playlists/pl.u-JPAZE8Gul2rRBZ0?omit%5Bresource%5D=autos&views=featured-artists&extend=artistUrl%2CcomposerUrl%2CtrackCount%2CeditorialVideo&include=tracks&include%5Bplaylists%5D=curator&include%5Bsongs%5D=artists%2Ccomposers&fields%5Bartists%5D=name%2Curl%2Cartwork&art%5Burl%5D=f&l=en-us"

HEADERS = {
    "authorization": "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6IldlYlBsYXlLaWQifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJBTVBXZWJQbGF5IiwiaWF0IjoxNjA3OTcyMDQ5LCJleHAiOjE2MjM1MjQwNDl9.hHSg1_2xr_-Gj8ZWIhoRARUEyTygMYUlvgfunJr4PsGikIylISAsaqx25gBuOBVKnSTl2btA22FsYM0OUBNU3A",
    "Referer": "https://music.apple.com/",
}

response = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS).json()

for data in response["data"][0]["relationships"]["tracks"]["data"]:
    print("Song name: ", data["attributes"]["name"])
    print("Artist:", data["attributes"]["artistName"] + "\n")
```

Output:

```
Song name:  Sky Walker (feat. Travis Scott)
Artist: Miguel

Song name:  Location
Artist: Khalid

...And on...
```

Comment: Thank you! this worked perfectly but I'm having a hard time understanding this code. Do you think you could link me an article or something that would help me understand this better?

Comment: @xidonutz332 It's quite simple, when we do `response['bla']`, it accesses the value for the key `bla`. It's called dictionaries in python.

Comment: The way I was trying to do it was without the Apple music API because I don't have a developer account. What I don't understand is how the same code can sometimes run and sometimes not. Like right now it is running. I'm new to programming and so confused. If you could help me understand this I would appreciate that a lot.